# parsing json response that has multiple keys using flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http, dictionary, dart

I'm trying to get the values of these keys from this json response:

```
{
    "wlan": {
        "channel": 1,
        "ssid": "WLAN-25UR7J",
        "mac": "00:17:91:80:22:96",
        "inet": [
            {
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                "ip": "192.168.2.112",
                "family": "IPv4"
            }
        ],
        "stationinfo": {
            "signal": -48,
            "channelwidth": 0,
            "bitrate": 72.2
        },
        "mode": "station",
        "encryption": "WPA2-PSK"
    }
}
```

I could get the values from wlan key by using this method.

```
json.decode(response.body)['wlan']['channel']
```

But I didn't work on the rest values like getting netmask or bitrate for example.

Comment: Have you tried using `json.decode(response.body)['wlan']['inet'][0]['netmask']`?

Comment: thanks a lot, no i didn't , it worked for inet key , but how please for stationinfo 
json.decode(response.body)['wlan']['inet'][1]['signal']
or
json.decode(response.body)['wlan']['inet']['stationinfo'][0]['signal']

Comment: ['wlan']['stationinfo']['signal'] worked great, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For netmask, you can access it like this:

```
json.decode(response.body)['wlan']['inet'][0]['netmask']
```

For bitrate, you can access it by:

```
json.decode(response.body)['wlan']['stationinfo']['bitrate']
```

If values inside any key is an array, either access them via index like `value[0]` or you can simply iterate the array and do the necessary action.